# Yii URLManager rule for multiple controller action parameters

Tags: php, yii

I'm desiring to use this url:

```
index.php/form/2/fields/all
```

To output a list of fields with the same form id. Currently, I have a Form crud and a Fields crud.

**FieldsController.php**

```
public function actionAll()
{
  if (isset($_GET['form']))
  {
    $form_id = $_GET['form'];
    $model=$this->model()->findAllByAttributes(array('FORM_ID'=>$form_id), 'order'=> 'POSITION DESC');
    $this->render('all', array('model' => $model));
  }
  else
  {
    $this->render('error');
  }
}
```

What would the URLManager rule be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add named param with rule:

```
'form/<form:\d+>/fields/all' => 'fields/all'
```

You can even omit `form`

```
'<form:\d+>/fields/all' => 'fields/all'
```

Which will produce url `10/fields/all`

Comment: Would be: 'form/<form:\d+>/fields/<fields:\d+>/edit' => 'fields/edit'